# Cloudwatch Insights - how to aggregate over time avg response time by url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I've an application log that has this format

timestamp, url, responsetime

Using AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights, how could i calculate and graphview (Line graph on Visualisation TAb)  the average response time by url, to find out what url is causing response time increase during the day on what moment?

I know how to parse and use the stat avg, but i could not find a way on group by url and avg over time.

*edit01*

An important restriction, i don't know the url's before processing and they could change, so a bonus to a solution where the url's are dynamically asigned.

Thanks,

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this? I have a similar use case.

Comment: Hi @activelearner, not until now. Sorry. If you find some aceptable working solution, would like to hear about it.